# Writing an email reminding an employer about my internship

Tags: interviewing, email

I was interviewed last week Thursday. The interviewer said I passed and she asked me when I could start and discuss my internship but she didn’t contact me. This might be because she's only an employee and not an official on the department. I sent my final requirements to the HR department and she said she'll email about when I should start. I asked her if I can discuss it with my department (where I was interviewed) but she said it’s not necessary.

It's been a week now and I have not received any email or call. How can I write something to remind her about my internship without being rude and too formal?

Answer (score 1):

You could send a polite email thanking her for the opportunity to interview with her, saying how much you're looking forward to working there, and asking if there is anything you still need to do before you start. That can begin an email conversation with your contact, and after she replies it would be appropriate for you to ask if she knows when your start date would be, and if not, how soon you can expect to find out.

Answer (score 1):

If it is imperative that you start the internship soon I would definitely email her.

Otherwise I would just wait it out and interview at a couple of other places, if that is a possibility, and see if you can find something better.

If you do choose to contact them remember to be polite but try not to be overly formal. Just be your polite self.

Comment: I hope 'defiantly' means 'definitely'.

Comment: @DJClayworth awww, it was much more fun to read the first way.

Answer (score 1):

**Remind them that you’re extremely interested.**

After about a week and a half has gone by you’ll have had even more time to reflect on the opportunity and your interview.  When you follow up, be sure to communicate that you’ve been thinking about it and remain really excited and enthusiastic.

**Tell them why you’re a great fit for the position**

In the interview you hopefully explained why you would be an asset to the company and a perfect fit for the job.  No harm in reminding your interviewer the types of skills you bring to the table and how you can make an immediate impact. It won’t be new information, but it’s worth emphasizing.

**(if applicable) Show off an accomplishment**

This won’t always be possible, but in certain fields and situations, you may have a recent accomplishment to show off.  For example, if you work in PR and have just got your company some amazing press you could share it. If you have organized an event that went off without a hitch, you can mention that.

**Ask about next steps**

The most important part of the “follow up” is to find out what’s next.  While you reaching out won’t be able to speed up the process, the goal is to get information so you are in the loop.  Even great companies will be transparent with you about what types of things are unfolding in the process and what the timeline looks like.  They will also let you know if they need additional information from you.

Try something as follows and fill in the gaps that apply to you.

> Dear [interviewer],
>
> Thank you again for the time you spent with me last [enter day you
>   spoke].  Since our interview, I’ve been thinking a lot about the
>   [insert job name] and I remain incredibly excited about it.  I
>   know that my past experience with [experience at company] will make me an
>   incredible asset to [company name].  I wanted to check in on next
>   steps in the process. Please let me know if I can provide
>   any additional information and if you have any information on what’s
>   next.
>
> Best wishes,